# What common weak choice principles are preserved by forcing?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice, forcing

It is well-known that if you force over a model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ you get another model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$. Also basic is that the Axiom of Choice itself plays no real part in the mechanics of forcing (so that one can force over models of $\mathsf{ZF}$ to get another model of $\mathsf{ZF}$, though probably not one in which the Axiom of Choice holds). I am curious whether any of the more common weak choice principles are preserved by forcing. That is, for which $\mathsf{X}$ is it the case that $M[G] \vDash \mathsf{ZF}+\mathsf{X}$ whenever $M \vDash \mathsf{ZF}+\mathsf{X}$, $\mathbb{P} \in M$, and $G$ is $\mathbb{P}$-generic over $M$?

In particular, I would be interested in the following:

- The Axiom of Countable Choice, $\mathsf{CC}$: for any sequence $( X_n )_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of nonempty sets, the product $\prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}} X_n$ is nonempty.
- The Axiom of Dependent Choice, $\mathsf{DC}$: if $R$ is a binary relation on a nonempty set $X$ such that for each $x \in X$ there is a $y \in X$ such that $x \mathrel{R} y$, then there is a sequence $( x_n )_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $X$ such that $x_n \mathrel{R} x_{n+1}$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
- The Ultrafilter Theorem, $\mathsf{UF}$: given any filter $\mathcal{F}$ of subsets of a nonempty set $X$, there is an ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}$ on $X$ with $\mathcal{U} \supseteq \mathcal{F}$.

I'm pretty sure that first is not preserved, I'm pretty agnostic on the second, and I'm inclined to think that the last may be preserved. This is more of a gut feeling than anything else so it can be safely ignored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None of these things need to be preserved in general.

> *Monro, G. P.*, [**On generic extensions without the axiom of choice**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2273318), J. Symb. Log. 48, 39-52 (1983). [ZBL0522.03034](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0522.03034).

There Monro proves that all three can be violated by forcing. In fact, we can show that if $\sf DC$ or even $\sf AC_\omega$ are preserved by generic extension (and it's enough to consider well-orderable forcings), then $\sf AC_{WO}$ holds. You can find some details [in this MathOverflow thread](https://mathoverflow.net/q/307269/7206).

We can show that $\sf DC$ is preserved under *proper* forcing (see my paper with David Asperó, [Dependent Choice, Properness, and Generic Absoluteness](https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.04077)), and in general it is also not hard to show that $\sf DC_{<\kappa}$ is preserved under $\kappa$-closed forcings (well, also $\kappa$-proper forcings, I suppose, but those are not well-behaved as proper forcings are with respect to $\omega$). But we don't have a nice condition for $\sf AC_\kappa$ (without $\sf DC_\kappa$, that is) or the Boolean Prime Ideal theorem (or even weaker versions such as the Ordering Principle).

On a more positive side, we can define a family of principles called **Kinna–Wagner Principles**, where $\sf KWP_\alpha$ states that every set can be injected into $\mathcal P^\alpha(\eta)$ for some ordinal $\eta$. Then we can show that if $\alpha$ is a limit (or $0$) then $\sf KWP_\alpha$ is preserved in forcing extensions, and in general forcing can violate at most one level in the Kinna–Wagner hierarchy. You can find more about this in one of my recent papers, [Guide to the Bristol model: Gazing into the Abyss](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.04514).

Finally, since we mentioned MathOverflow, [this](https://mathoverflow.net/q/76995/7206) and [this](https://mathoverflow.net/q/77000/7206) are both relevant to your question.

Comment: Perhaps KWP is not common, so shouldn't be included. But I think that it should be common.